# Salesforce TLS 1.0 disable test link tls1test responding grant_type not support

Tags: salesforce

Since Salesforce TLS1.0 is getting disabled on July 22nd I was testing as suggested in the below url https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Salesforce-disabling-TLS-1-0&language=en_US&type=1 .
  We interact with salesforce from backend server via REST API Initiatilly we do a grant_type=password for getting the access token and instance_url.  Its pointed to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token and it works now.  As mentioned in the help url tried to point it to  https://tls1test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token   and it gives me an error {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"} .   Tried in the below format from linux command line it gives me the same response.

```
 curl -v https://tls1test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password&client_id=<>&client_secret=<>&username=username%40domain.com&password=<>" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```